# Dead letters encountered in elasticmq plugin in Grails

Tags: scala, grails, groovy, jms

I got this error when processing thousands of data:

```
[INFO] [01/06/2016 19:04:00.511] [elasticmq-akka.actor.default-  dispatcher-4] [akka://elasticmq/deadLetters] Message  [scala.collection.immutable.Nil$] from Actor[akka://elasticmq/user/$a/$b#1345840207] to Actor[akka://elasticmq/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
| Error 2016-01-06 19:04:00,502 [elasticmq-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] ERROR sqs.TheSQSRestServerBuilder$$anon$1  - Exception when running routes
Message: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://elasticmq/user/$a/$b#1345840207]] after [21000 ms]
Line | Method
->> 334 | apply$mcV$sp     in akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1
```

---

```
|   117 | run              in akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$7
|   599 | unbatchedExecute in scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$
|   109 | execute          in scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class
|   597 | execute . . . .  in scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$
|   467 | executeTask      in akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder
|   419 | executeBucket$1  in akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8
|   423 | nextTick         in     ''
|   375 | run . . . . . .  in     ''
^   745 | run              in java.lang.Thread
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: `Content is not allowed on prolog` is typically an XML parsing exception. Look for illegal XML characters in whatever XML is involved.

Comment: try to check in hex editor to find out any BOM at the beginning of xml file

Comment: Thanks @nattyddubbs I will check the content of it.

Comment: Thanks @Rao, I will check it .